# Remove unwanted character from string

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd
from csv import writer


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/reviews/casino-friday"
driver.get(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

product = []

pays=soup.select("div#tabPayments")

for pay in pays:
    try:
        t4=pay.select_one(" .review-details-wrapper+ .review-details-wrapper .review-details__item:nth-child(2) .review-details__text")
        t4 = [i for i in t4 if i.text]
    except:
        pass
    
supports = soup.find("div", {"id": "tabCustomers"})
supports = supports.find("div", {"class": "review-details__text"})
email = "Support Email:"+supports.text.replace("\n", "").split(":")[1]
print(email)
```

they show me output like that

```
['\nSupport\nEmail:\nsupport@casinofriday.com\n', '\n']
```

but I want output like that:

```
 Support Email:support@casinofriday.com
```

I want to remove all unwanted character from my string  kindly recommend any solution these is the page link https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/reviews/casino-friday

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import pandas as pd
from csv import writer


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://www.askgamblers.com/online-casinos/reviews/casino-friday"
driver.get(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

product = []

pays = soup.select("div#tabPayments")

for pay in pays:
    try:
        t4 = pay.select_one(
            " .review-details-wrapper+ .review-details-wrapper .review-details__item:nth-child(2) .review-details__text")
        t4 = [i.replace("\n", "") for i in t4 if i.text]
    except:
        pass
    print(t4)
supports = soup.find("div", {"id": "tabCustomers"})
supports = supports.find("div", {"class": "review-details__text"})
email = "Support Email:"+supports.text.replace("\n", "").split(":")[1]
print(email)
```

**Output**

```
['EWallets:0-1 hours', 'Bank Transfers:1-7 days', 'Cheques:Not offered', 'Card Payments:1-7 days', 'Pending Time:0-24 hours']
Support Email:support@casinofriday.com
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: thank I have one  question more.....

Comment: I have want to remove  unwanted character from `pays` I have edit code you see that...

Comment: I Have changed the code according to the new question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could utilize two methods to achieve your goals: replace() and split() before appending.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove any unwanted characters in the string with use of `.replace()` method replacing the unwanted character with nothing, empty string.
Lets say your result string is stored in `product` string. So, to remove the unwanted `[` sign you can do this:

```py
product = product.replace('[', '')
```

Doing that for all the characters you want to remove will lead for code like this:

```py
product = product.replace('[', '')
product = product.replace('[', '')
product = product.replace('\n', '')
product = product.replace("'", "")
product = product.replace(",", "")
product = product.strip()
```

The final `strip()` removes leading and trailing spaces.